# How do I export my Google Fit data to iPhone and keep it in sync in the future?

Tags: ios, fitness, google-fit

I have used Google Fit on my Android phone for a while, and recently switched to the iPhone. How do I import my step counts and other fitness data into Apple Health on the iPhone from Google Fit?

Are there cross-platform cloud services that store this data in the cloud and have both iOS and Android clients so that I don't have this problem again the next time I switch phones?

I posted the same [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/257681/how-do-i-import-my-fitness-data-from-android-and-keep-it-in-sync-in-the-future) on apple.stackexchange.com to get answers from iOS users.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first part of your question - the Android part:

You export your Google Fit data by going to [Google Takeout](https://takeout.google.com/).  It is not exported from within the Fit app itself.

Takeout is part of Google's Data Liberation project.  It enables you to download a copy of your data held by Google and attached to your Google account.

The Fit data can be downloaded in TCX or CSV format.